# Connect to Docker API from Windows to external server

Tags: linux, docker, phpstorm

I am working on Windows and on a virtual machine (VirtualBox) I installed Ubuntu server with a Docker. Now I am struggling to define Docker on PhpStorm. It requires connecting to Docker socket which is not working for me.

From Windows, I can ping Ubuntu server with 192.168.56.101.

Could you give me some advice how can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please always state the exact IDE version you are using. If it's 2017.1.x -- try **2017.2 EAP build** -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/05/phpstorm-2017-2-early-access-program-is-open/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: Can you telnet to port 2376 of your Ubuntu server? It looks like you haven't enabled the TCP socket for the Docker service. http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/07/quick-tip-how-to-enable-docker-remote-api.html